# How to setup Google Cloud Compute Engine to manually move over our website and database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

Sounds like a silly question but hopefully someone here has the answer.

I want to start using Google Cloud for hosting our web and db. If we start small with say the following configuration (image attached). What happens if we outgrow that server and want to up it to say "n1-standard-32".. do we have to build out a new compute engine under that spec and then manually move over our website and database? Or is there simpler way of doing it like creating an image and then creating a new server based of the image? Can someone help me shed some light on this? TIA

[image: Configuration of server]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the instance type without having to recreate it from scratch.

To do this, you'll have to stop your GCE instance, edit instance properties and start it again. The whole process should take a few minutes.

PS: I've also noticed you may be using local SSD. I would not recommend using it for database, as it has reduced durability. Consider using Persistent Disk instead. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd